# FullHttpRequest to ByteBuff

Tags: httprequest, netty, bytebuffer

I would like to convert my FullHttpRequest object to the ByteBuf object, to avoid using encoding every time I write something on pipeline. What's the best way to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "avoid using encoding every time I write something on pipeline"?

Comment: I send many same requests. To optimize the code I'd like not to use HttpRequestEncode class on the pipeline (it invokes every time encode code), but create once a ByteBuf and writes ByteBuf object on the channel every time.

Comment: Why don't you just copy the code from `HttpRequestEncoder` that generates `ByteBuf` from HttpRequest?

Comment: I did it, but was not sure if there isn't better way to do it. Moreover, when I deleted HttpRequestEncoder() from the pipeline and just writeAndFlush ByteBuf on the channel, my client program freezes. Should I add any other handler on the pipeline?

Comment: This may not work with every request as some requests like `HEAD` get special treatment by the server, and you can't know its `HEAD` by only reading the response

Comment: So isn't it a good idea to create once per request one ByteBuf and resend it?

Comment: In general - no. But it could be a way to go in some situations. Do you perform `.duplicate()` or `retain()` when writing cached `ByteBuf`?

Comment: I use retain() method

Answer (score 1):

Netty uses `ByteBuf` to handle message encoding/decoding with great performance, in most of case, you don't need overhead of encoding same requests for multiple times.

If you really want to do that, you can initiate `HttpRequestEncoder` and `ChannelHandlerContext` by yourself, then invoke its `encode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg, List<Object> out)` method(you need create a subclass since its encode method is protected), then the encoded `ByteBuf` will be output to the List.

In a word, it's a little tricky to do, but it can work.